# Calculated column in datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I've a application with a datagrid in WPF with C#, I've 4 columns, and I need that the four column is calculated with respect to the other columns. I use IValueConverter, that works perfectly, but only calculates values of the column four when I change the row, and I need that when I change the cell 2 and 3, changes the 4 column.

This is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="grid">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <local:CalculatingConverter x:Key="CalculatingConverter" />
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Count}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Total"                  
                Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CalculatingConverter}}"
                />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

This is my code:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

        items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item1", Count = 2, Price = 10 });
        items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item2", Count = 5, Price = 20 });
        this.grid.ItemsSource = items;
    }
}
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private decimal price;
    private int count;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public string Name {            
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != name)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.Price)
            {
                price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public int Count {
        get
        {
            return count;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != count)
            {
                count = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public decimal TotalPrice
    {
        get { return Price * Count; }
    }
}
```

And this is my IConverter:

```
    public class CalculatingConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {

            return ((Item)value).Price * ((Item)value).Count;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you know where the values in these columns are coming from? Can you clarify what you mean by "to do it right off or change the first column"?

Comment: i need that , when in the first column i change the value, then the second column change value also.

Comment: Do you know where the values are coming from? How did you put them in the grid?

Comment: In the above code is placed the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally thanks to Ed Plunkett i implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`in my `item` class and in `Price` and `Count` force to call to `OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice")` and works perfectly:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private decimal price;
    private int count;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public string Name {            
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != name)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.Price)
            {
                price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice");
            }
        }
    }
    public int Count {
        get
        {
            return count;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != count)
            {
                count = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice");
            }
        }
    }
    public decimal TotalPrice
    {
        get { return Price * Count;  }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `Item` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event when any of its properties changes.

The trouble then is that there's no way for that binding to know what properties it needs to be watching for changes. One solution to that is to change your converter to `IMultiValueConverter` and change that binding to a `MultiBinding` which explicitly binds both `Price` and `Count`.

Another option for you, and this would be a much simpler option, would be to add a read only `TotalPrice` property to your `Item` class. That's what I would do.

```
public decimal TotalPrice {
    get { return Price * Count; }
}
```

Then, in your `Price` property, when `Price` changes, you would raise the `PropertyChanged` event for `TotalPrice` as well as for `Price`. And you would do the same for `Count`.

Then you could bind to `TotalPrice` very simply in the XAML with no converter at all. You might need to make the binding `Mode=OneWay`, since it's read only.

Let me know if you need more code examples.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `IValueConverter` for this. Use first column as your source (bind second column to first) and convert the value using your converter.

[MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_3).